# How to stop internally Hash Map Rehashing?

Tags: java, hashmap

To maintain 16 buckets even if 1000 records are added in HasMap.

To do this I found :
Setting the load factor to a higher value can only delay the rehashing process.

ex:-
HashMap m = new HashMap(16, 1);

Internal code is as follows:

```
void addEntry(int paramInt1, K paramK, V paramV, int paramInt2)
{
    if ((size >= threshold) && (null != table[paramInt2]))
    {
        resize(2 * table.length);
        paramInt1 = null != paramK ? hash(paramK) : 0;
        paramInt2 = indexFor(paramInt1, table.length);
    }
    createEntry(paramInt1, paramK, paramV, paramInt2);
}
```

if size >= threshold then how the condition is getting stopped?

suppose size is 1000 
and threashold = currentcapacity* 1

then it will be 1000> = 16 
how rehashing is stoped can anyone explain me ?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rehashing can be stopped if you know the maximum size your hashmap can ever grow to.

In the constructor,

```
HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor);
```

initialCapacity: is the capacity of the hashmap at the time of creation.

loadFactor: is what portion of initial capacity is to be filled for rehashing to take place.

E.G.  if the constructor is `HashMap(10,0.5);`

`10 * 0.5 = 5`, keys are inserted in the hash map and for the 6 th key rehashing will be done.

Now if you know the maximum  size your hasmap can grow to is 1000, create the hashmap using `HashMap(1001,1);` and your hashmap will never be rehashed(given the number of keys in the hashmap always remain less than or equals to 1000).

### Update:

Try with:

```
    m.put(new testing(1), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(2), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(3), "xyz");
    m.put(new testing(4), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(5), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(6), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(7), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(8), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(9), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(10), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(11), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(12), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(13), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(14), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(15), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(16), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(17), "abc");
    m.put(new testing(18), "abc");
```

Comment: Even if i do  HashMap(16,1) then also rehashing stops

Comment: How it is working internally ?  as you told 16 * 1 = 16 keys are inserted in the hash map and for the 17 th key rehashing will be done.,,, but if we give this HashMap(16,1)  constructor . even if i put 17th key value pair the bucket size will be 16 only ? how it is doing internally?

Comment: While creating HashMap(16,1), threshold for the hashMap is set as 16*1 = 16, while adding the 17th key, it checks for the condition if the size for the hashmap is >= threshold. If yes, it calls for the resize() and the size is doubled. This means that the bucket size has now been doubled to 32 and is no more 16.

Comment: it wont increase , you can check

Comment: I have a doubt if rehashing stops if we do HashMap(16,1).

Comment: it stops let me give you a program , you will be able to see that

Comment: The keys are repeating in your case.there are 2 instances where you have used new testing(5) and also have overridden equals() in the testing class. That makes the 2 keys same. I have added a series of put statements which might help you understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204536/discussion-between-abj1305-and-kavya).